# Maven Fat Jar Not Executing

Tags: apache-flink, maven-assembly-plugin

My maven is as below, I am reading Kafka messages using Flink consumer, it working fine with stand alone run,

```
<dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
           <artifactId>java-driver-core</artifactId>
           <version>4.8.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
           <artifactId>flink-connector-cassandra_2.11</artifactId>
           <version>1.11.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
           <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
           <version>1.11.0</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
           <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.12</artifactId>
           <version>1.11.0</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
           <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_2.12</artifactId>
           <version>1.11.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
           <artifactId>flink-clients_2.12</artifactId>
           <version>1.11.0</version>
       </dependency>
      .
      .
      .
   </dependencies>
   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.3.0</version>
               <configuration>
                   <descriptorRefs>
                       <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                   </descriptorRefs>
                   <finalName>streaming-job-1.0-RELEASE</finalName>
                   <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                   <archive>
                       <manifest>
                           <mainClass>com.sample.SampleJob</mainClass>
                       </manifest>
                   </archive>
               </configuration>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>make-assembly</id>
                       <phase>package</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>single</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

and Java Flink Kafka Consumer piece of code is,

```
final FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> flinkConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>
                                             (kafkaTopicName, new SimpleStringSchema(), prop);
        flinkConsumer.setStartFromEarliest();

        final DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(flinkConsumer);
        DataStream<Person> sensorStreaming = stream.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, Person>() {
            @Override
            public void flatMap(String value, Collector<Person> out) throws Exception {
               
            }
        });
        System.out.println("env >>>= "+env);
        env.execute();
```

When i run the code standalone works fine and after creating Far Jar is not working,

Stacktrace is

```
env >>>= org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment@533b266e
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ExecutorFactory found to execute the application.
    at org.apache.flink.core.execution.DefaultExecutorServiceLoader.getExecutorFactory(DefaultExecutorServiceLoader.java:84)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1803)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1713)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment.execute(LocalStreamEnvironment.java:74)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1699)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1681)
```

I can see all the dependencies are inside Fat Jar,

[image]

Comment: Could you share the whole Flink code you are using? Ideally it is the whole project which one can build. Moreover, it would be interesting to see how exactly you run the Flink job in both cases (which command line parameters, from IDE, via web UI?).

Comment: Why are you mixing 2.11 and 2.12 ? Could you please try to depend either on _2.11 or _2.12, but not both at the same time ?

Comment: How are you executing Flink? Stacktrace looks like you are still using standalone executor (LocalStreamEnvironment). That only works if you have also included flink_clients in your fat jar.

Comment: @TillRohrmann - Sure i will share you the code.  @Mikalai - Sorry it's my bad, i changed into _2.11 for all but not luck. @Arvid - i use ```private final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();``` and included```flink-clients_2.11``` artifact with ```1.11.0``` version.

Comment: @TillRohrmann https://gist.github.com/thangavel-projects/b310b7f094488a184efceec0adb1f1d3  I just tried with ```LocalStreamEnvironment``` also but no luck.

Comment: Would it be possible to simply share the Github repo? Then one could simply clone it and build it locally. `LocalStreamEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment()` won't work. Please post the code which causes the problems but w/o this change.

Comment: @Till - here you go, https://github.com/thangavel-projects/kafka-streaming-sample.git  JFYI -  I didn't modify anything, please go ahead.

Comment: @ThangavelLoganathan I could build the jar and submit it to a Flink cluster and it seemed to work. Maybe you need to give us a bit more details on how exactly you are submitting the job and which Flink version your cluster is running.

Comment: I installed Flink 1.11 on MacOS and i can access using ```localhost:8081``` runs fine.  After that I am running ```java -jar <fat.jar name>```  This binaries reads data from Kafka. Is there anything missing form my side?  Could you please explain it? Thank you!

Comment: I am sorry i think https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/cli.html right approach to run.

Comment: It works fine, thanks you so much @Till.

Comment: @Till - I need to register a class ```com.datastax.driver.extras.codecs.jdk8.InstantCodec```   i read the https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/custom_serializers.html the ```InstantCodec``` is 3rd party class with out serializer.  any way to register it?